# Bug in deriving PCA

Tags: statistics, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Ok, I feel dumb. From what follows it looks like there is a bug in my reasoning.

---

There are $N$ datapoints $\boldsymbol{x}_n$. $\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}$ will be the direction of my principal component, so that $\boldsymbol{y} = \hat{\boldsymbol{u}} \boldsymbol{x}^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}$ and $\left \| \hat{\boldsymbol{u}} \right \|^2=1$.

$$\bar{\boldsymbol{x}} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}\boldsymbol{x}_n,$$
$$\bar{\boldsymbol{y}} = \hat{\boldsymbol{u}} \bar{\boldsymbol{x}}^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}.$$

Then there is the tricky part, where I compute the variance of $\boldsymbol{y}$ (which I want to maximise, i.e. finding the direction that spreads the most the data apart).

If I write as follows:

$$\text{var}[\boldsymbol{y}] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{x}_n^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}-\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}})^2=
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{x}_n^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}-\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}})^\top(\boldsymbol{x}_n^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}-\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}^\top \hat{\boldsymbol{u}})=
\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top\mathbf{S}\hat{\boldsymbol{u}},$$
$$\mathbf{S}=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{x}_n -\bar{\boldsymbol{x}} )(\boldsymbol{x}_n -\bar{\boldsymbol{x}})^\top.$$
And then, with Lagrange multiplier over the constrain $\left \| \hat{\boldsymbol{u}} \right \|^2=1$, I get $$\mathbf{S}\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}=\lambda\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}.$$

If I write instead the variance in the following way, everything collapse...

$$\text{var}[\boldsymbol{y}] = \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top \boldsymbol{x}_n-\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top \bar{\boldsymbol{x}})^2=
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top \boldsymbol{x}_n-\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top \bar{\boldsymbol{x}})^\top (\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top \boldsymbol{x}_n-\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top \bar{\boldsymbol{x}})=\\
=\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{x}_n -\bar{\boldsymbol{x}})^\top\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}\hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top(\boldsymbol{x}_n -\bar{\boldsymbol{x}}) \color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{=}}}
\require{cancel} \color{red}{\cancel{\color{black}{
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\boldsymbol{x}_n -\bar{\boldsymbol{x}})^\top(\boldsymbol{x}_n -\bar{\boldsymbol{x}})=
\text{var}[\boldsymbol{x}]
}}}$$

Does anyone understand what is going on here? o.O

Comment: Why can the trick be used?? It involved in minus to matrix with different dimension. one is 1 by p , the other one is p by 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last line you seem to be writing $\hat{\boldsymbol{u}} \hat{\boldsymbol{u}}^\top = \mathbb{I}_D$, but this won't hold if the dimension of your points fulfils $D \ge 2$. You will have $\hat {\boldsymbol{u}}^\top \hat {\boldsymbol{u}} = \|\hat {\boldsymbol{u}}\|^2 = 1$, but not the other way round.

Comment: LOL, you got it right and soon! Thanks! This was literally driving me crazy xD (and I have to wait 1 more minute before being able to accept your prompt answer, LOL)

Comment: Why can the trick be used?? It involved in minus to matrix with different dimension. one is 1 by p , the other one is p by 1?